# Custom "wp_login.php?action=lostpassword" and reset password

Tags: customization

I've got a custom registration form which works. Then, on this form, I have the "forget password" link. This one is not working very well. The "forget password" form is OK with its design; enter a login or email address to receive an email and to change the password.

I have 2 cases :

- If the login is empty or false
- If the login is right

I have the following code :

```
//traitement des erreurs de connexion
$errorlost2 = false;
if ( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
    $user_login = $_POST['user_login'];
    $user = username_exists( $user_login );
    echo 'user_login =' .$user_login; // renvoi bien le login
    echo 'user =' .$user; // renvoi bien l'ID du user si login exist
    if ( $user == NULL ) {
        header( 'location:lostpassword' );
        $errorlost2 = true;
    } else {
    }
}

    <div id="check-lostpassord" >
    <div class="titre">
        <h1> <img src="<?php echo $cheminsite; ?>/images/lion.png" alt="lion"> <?php echo $lang['TITRE-CONNEXION']; ?>      </h1>
        <div class="titre-underline"> </div>
   </div> 

   <div class="connexion-lostpassword"> 
    <div id="box-lostpassword">
            <p class="message"><?php echo $lang['lostpassword_message']; ?></p> 
            </br>
                <div class="error">
                    <p id="lostpasswordform-erreur2">
                        <?php 
                        if ($errorlost2):
                        echo 'TEST';
                            echo $lang['lostpassword_error2']; 
                        endif
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

            <!-- http://club-d-affaires.de/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword -->
            <form name="lostpasswordform" class="lostpasswordform" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>" method="post" id="lostpasswordform" >

        <br class="clear"></br>
          <p id="text-form">
            <label for="user_login" ><?php echo $lang['lostpassword_login']; ?>*:<br />
            <br class="clear"></br>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
          </p>
            <br class="clear"></br>
            <br class="clear"></br>
           <?php do_action('login_form', 'resetpass'); ?>
            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="user-submit" id="wp-submit" class="user-submit" value="<?php echo $lang['lostpassword_envoyer']; ?>" tabindex="1002"/>
            <?php $reset = $_GET['reset']; if($reset == true) {?> </br></br> <p> <?php echo $lang['lostpassword_confirm'];?></p> 
            <a href="<?php "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>connexion/?langue=<?php echo $langue; ?>" >
            <h2> <?php  echo $lang['lostpassword_connect']; ?> </h2>    </a>        <?php } ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?reset=true" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </p>
        </form>

       </div> <!-- fin box-connexion -->
    </div> <!-- fin connexion -->
</div> <!-- fin connexion -->
```

The problem is at the beginning of `<form>` :

Point 1 - Error message, if login is false or empty, works if I have :

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" class="lostpasswordform" action="" method="post" id="lostpasswordform">
```

Point 2 - Send an email, with the link to modify the password, works if I have :

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" class="lostpasswordform" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>" method="post" id="lostpasswordform" >
```

The `action=""` is the problem here. How can I have point 1 and point 2 working at the same time?

Comment: ok, I didn't see that i didn't really understood the use of posting code. Sorry.

Comment: The thing that put problem is at the beginning of <form>.

point1 (error message if login false or empty) works if i have action=""

point 2 (send an Email with the link to modifie the passsword) works if I have action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>"

 So, the point action:"" is a pb here. I don't know how to have point 1 and point 2 working in the same time.

Do you have an idea about this?

many thanks for your help 

Timama

Answer (score 1):

try it:

Runs after the user submits a new password during password reset but before the new password is actually set.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/password_reset